# EF Core 2.1 saying multiple columns have been added to the primary key but they havent

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I was trying to make a relational model using EF Core 2.1 but while adding migrations I was receiving an error about multiple columns being bound to the primary key. This doesnt appear to be the case and I am not sure why it thinks it is.

I was able to replicate with a very simple project, below, and this was the error.

> The keys {'ParentId'} on 'OwnedEntity' and {'Id'} on 'Entity' are both mapped to 'Entities.PK_Entities' but with different columns ({'ParentId'} and {'Id'}).

This error comes from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/2.1.4/src/EFCore.Relational/Infrastructure/RelationalModelValidator.cs#L444)

Removing the ColumnAttribute allows the Add-Migration to continue/succeed but I really didnt want to have the `Owned` type prepended to every column.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace OwnedTypeTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<TestDBContext>(o=>o.UseSqlServer("test"));
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) { }
    }
    public class TestDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
        public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    }
    public class Entity
    {
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public OwnedEntity Owned { get; set; }
    }
    [Owned]
    public class OwnedEntity
    {
        [Column(nameof(ParentId))]
        public System.Guid ParentId { get; set; }
        [Column(nameof(Parent))]
        public Entity Parent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If I override OnModelCreating like below I get the commented results

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    Debugger.Launch();
    var et = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes(typeof(Entity)).First();
    var keys = et.GetKeys();
    var keyCount = keys.Count(); // 1
    var key = keys.First().ToString(); // Key: Entity.Id PK
    var properties = keys.First().Properties;
    var propertyCount = properties.Count(); // 1
    var property = properties.First().ToString(); // Property: Entity.Id (Guid) Required PK AfterSave:Throw ValueGenerated.OnAdd 0 0 0 -1 0
}
```

For completeness here is my csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="2.6.375" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.4" />

  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Is this a bug or am I missing some implicit behavior of EF? If I am, what is happening?

Comment: Probably yet another owned type [current shortcoming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#current-shortcomings) or a bug. In both cases this is question for https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I wasn't misusing or missing something first.